# Changing color of Ball Type in swift 2

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, skspritenode

I am trying to fill my ball in my swift game with two colors> I want them to be half white and half blue. I have tried changed the ball to a SKSpriteNode but it ruins the whole project and all of the physics. Is there anyway to make a Ball type two colors or place an image over the ball? thanks

Comment: what is `Ball Type`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use `SKSpriteNode`, try to use `SKShapeNode`:

```
let textureBall : SKTexture! = SKTexture(imageNamed:"ball.png") 
let ballSize: CGSize = textureBall.size
ball = SKShapeNode.init(circleOfRadius: ballSize.width/2)
ball.fillTexture = textureBall
ball.strokeColor = UIColor.clearColor()
ball.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
ball.name = "ball"
ball.zPosition = 1
ball.fillColor = UIColor.redColor() // use the color you want
self.addChild(ball)
```

Comment: is there anyway to do this without changing it from type: ball

Comment: sprite.color = .whiteColor() or always for SKSpriteNode the action SKAction.colorizeWithColor()